# Buildfire: How can I get the iframe source ID or name?

Tags: buildfire

How can I identify the iframe source ID or name? Having issues with plugin working on Apple devices and one proposed fix was to tag the iframe source ID in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from querystring parameter `fid` in `window.location.href`. I would not rely too much on it since it is not documented and hence might change.